# Which artifact to choose for servlet api?

Tags: maven, sonatype

The below sonatype endpoint for servlet api returns 5 different artifacts : http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/lucene/search?sha1=3fc542fe8bb8164e8d3e840fe7403bc0518053c0

Why are there 5 different artifacts returned? Based on the group id, artifact id & version of a given artifact I am going to create a maven dependency. So for example :

```
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
 <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
 <version>2.4.public_draft</version>
```

becomes :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
<version>2.4.public_draft</version> 
</dependency>
```

Which artifact should I choose or does it matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each artifact returns the same response jar file when I convert it to a dependency so it does not matter which artifact details I use.